# Capybara + Poltergeist with Database-cleaner not finding FactoryGirl records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I'm writing integration tests and creating records with `FactoryGirl`. My controllers are throwing `RecordNotFound` when the test has `js: true` (with Poltergeist) even though they are found in a non-js test (without Poltergeist).

I do have `use_transactional_fixtures` set to `false` and `DatabaseCleaner.strategy` set to `:truncation`, which seemingly covers every existing SO question on this issue. I tried substituting Selenium (with Firefox) for Poltergeist but I get the same result. *ETA* I started a fresh Rails 4.2.3 project with RSpec-Rails 3.3.3, Capybara 2.4.4, Poltergeist 1.6.0, PhantomJS 1.9.8, Database Cleaner 1.4.1 and get the same results when testing a new, unedited scaffold.

**Why aren't my records found by Poltergeist?** Any suggestions would be helpful, since I've been at this for hours.

The first two tests pass while the last fails on the second line with `RecordNotFound`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

before :each do
  @vehicle = FactoryGirl.create :vehicle
end

it "should work on vehicle path" do
  visit vehicle_path(@vehicle)
  expect(page).to have_content @vehicle.name
end

describe "with js", js: true do
  it "should work on root path" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content "My Root"
  end

  it "should work on vehicle path" do
    expect(Vehicle.find(@vehicle.to_param)).to be_present # no error
    visit vehicle_path(@vehicle) # error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in controller from Vehicle.find (same as above line)
    expect(page).to have_content @vehicle.name
  end
end
```

Here is my pared-down spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist' 

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new app, window_size: [1600, 1200], js_errors: false
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.order = "random"

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation) # moving to before :each doesn't help
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation # moving to before :each doesn't help
  end

  config.around :each do |example| # refactoring as before/after with .start/.clean doesn't help
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning { example.run }
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you also have a rails_helper.rb -- if so please post

Comment: @TomWalpole No rails_helper, this is AFAIK all of my spec config (I "inherited" the project from a previous dev).

Comment: try setting the DatabaseCleaner.strategy in a before(:each) rather than :suite

Comment: @TomWalpole tried that and tried moving `clean_with` as well, no dice

Comment: The database_cleaner example https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example doesn't use cleaning, but rather uses a before and after, I don't think that should matter, but it wouldn't hurt to try - other than that I'm out of ideas since it looks right to me

Comment: @TomWalpole Thanks, but I already tried that as well :( I'm wondering if this could be an OS X-related issue? I'm pretty stumped here

Comment: I guess the last thing would be look for :transaction in your code, and see if there is anywhere else possibly overriding the :truncation setting

Comment: @TomWalpole `grep -r ":transaction" .` gets me nothing

Comment: actually how is your 'before :each do' working -- RSpec only defines 3 methods on the global object- describe, shared_examples, shared_context

Comment: I created a fresh project and basically copied over your setup, and it appears to work fine -- you can see it here - https://github.com/twalpole/demo_truncation  -  not sure what the difference with your setup and attempt at a fresh app are

Comment: Try changing before :each to let. You are not modifying object so it's not needed to recreate it all the time.

Comment: @TomWalpole I was able to fix the issue by taking your configuration and modifying it for what I needed. I'm wondering if my attempt at using a single `spec_helper` (leaving out separate `rails_helper`) is what caused problems. In any case, if you want to answer the question with your repo, I could accept it, unless I should just delete the question? Not sure of proper SO protocol here. Regardless, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a fresh project and basically copied over your setup, and it appears to work fine -- you can see it here - http://github.com/twalpole/demo_truncation - not sure what the difference with your setup and attempt at a fresh app are

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is either, but this helped me create a working solution. One potential difference: I attempted to use just a `spec_helper`, omitting the `rails_helper`. I now have both as in your project, so potentially that was the reason.